# Is it possible to embed jasper reports into a Python application?

Tags: java, python, jasper-reports, report

If not, what other reporting alternatives would you recommend (free)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [jasper server](http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperserver) out there you might want to have a look at.

---

I quote from its homepage: "JasperServer is the **free**, open source report server for JasperReports and OLAP analysis."

Comment: I quote from its homepage: "JasperServer is the **free**, open source report server for JasperReports and OLAP analysis.",

Comment: Ah yes, this is wonderful. Last time I checked, this was a paid resource. They must have recently come out with a community edition...

Comment: Just to clarify: at no point it time was it true that there was a paid version of JasperServer but not a free one. There has always been both a free (GPL or AGPL for $0) and a commercial version.